# For what values of $x$ does the series $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant 1}\sin(0.99\sin(0.99\dots\sin(0.99x)\dots))_{n-times}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

For what values of $x$ does the series 
$$\sum\limits_{n\geqslant 1}\sin(0.99\sin(0.99\dots\sin(0.99x)\dots))_{n-times}$$

converge, diverge and converge absolutely.

I'm stuck on how to approach this problem as clearly ratio test won't work and I can't see how I could use the comparison test. Clearly it converges when $sinx=0$; I've tried finding the progression of values after each $\sin(0.99...$ but it seems kind of random.

Answer (score 5):

Should converge absolutely for all x. After all, $-1\le a_1=\sin(0.99x)\le1$, and then $|a_{n+1}|=|\sin(0.99a_n)|<0.99|a_n|$, so $|a_{n+1}|<0.99^n$.